# Flutter Awesome Notifications icon color stays black with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, awesome-notifications

I'm using the awesome_notifications package for Flutter. When I initialize AwesomeNotifications, I set the defaultColor to Colors.blue.

```
defaultColor: Colors.blue,
```

When I send a push notification locally, the push notification icon is blue. But when I send the push notification from Firebase, the push notification icon is black.

I want the push notification icon to be blue when I send the notification from Firebase too.

In the _firebaseMessagingHandler, I am creating the notification like this:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotificationFromJsonData(message.data);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to set the color in the message.data?